# How can I get xslt file from input xml file?

Tags: xml, xslt

In my java code I'm using following input like this:

```
<offers>
  <offer>
    <offerDetails>
    <offerCode>AlertsecTotalEndpointSecurity</offerCode>
    <Locale value="en_US">
    <offerName>Alertsec Total Endpoint Security</offerName>
    <offerDescription>Alertsec Total Endpoint Security</offerDescription>
    <usagePrice></usagePrice>
         <compare>0</compare>
       <customize>0</customize>
    <unitPriceDesc>User</unitPriceDesc>

    </Locale>
   <offerprices>
   <offerprice type="ISV">
     <priceid>FD31086465874D5BE0437E0910AC671A</priceid>
     <parentpriceid></parentpriceid>
     <minQty>10</minQty>
     <staticQuantity>N</staticQuantity>
     <minRetailPrice>0</minRetailPrice>
     <isprivate>N</isprivate>
     <isbundle>N</isbundle>
     <currencyid>1001</currencyid>
     <charges>
      <charge>
    <chargetype>
      <chargetypeid>JCB_CHRG_TYP_00001</chargetypeid>
    </chargetype>
    <chargeid>FD31086465894D5BE0437E0910AC671A</chargeid>
    <chargeperiodid>JCB_CHRG_PER_00002</chargeperiodid>
    <ratingtype>RF</ratingtype>
    <charge_calculation>S</charge_calculation>
    <entity_type>OFFERPRICE</entity_type>
    <prorate_on_cancellation>Y</prorate_on_cancellation>
    <balanceimpacts>
      <balanceimpact>
        <scaledPrice>1</scaledPrice>
        <fixedPrice>0</fixedPrice>
        <unitqty>1</unitqty>
        <prorate>Y</prorate>
        <resourceid>1001</resourceid>
        <resourcetype>CURRENCY</resourcetype>
        <pricetype>A</pricetype>
      </balanceimpact>
    </balanceimpacts>
      </charge>
      <charge>
    <chargetype>
      <chargetypeid>JCB_CHRG_TYP_00002</chargetypeid>
    </chargetype>
    <chargeid>FD310864658D4D5BE0437E0910AC671A</chargeid>
    <chargeperiodid>JCB_CHRG_PER_00005</chargeperiodid>
    <ratingtype>O</ratingtype>
    <charge_calculation>S</charge_calculation>
    <entity_type>OFFERPRICE</entity_type>
    <prorate_on_cancellation>Y</prorate_on_cancellation>
    <balanceimpacts>
      <balanceimpact>
        <scaledPrice>0</scaledPrice>
        <fixedPrice>0</fixedPrice>
        <unitqty>1</unitqty>
        <prorate>Y</prorate>
        <resourceid>1001</resourceid>
        <resourcetype>CURRENCY</resourcetype>
        <pricetype>A</pricetype>
      </balanceimpact>
    </balanceimpacts>
      </charge>
     </charges>
   </offerprice>
   <offerprice type="ISV">
     <priceid>FD30096C19AB4681E0437E0910ACD407</priceid>
     <parentpriceid></parentpriceid>
     <minQty>10</minQty>
     <staticQuantity>N</staticQuantity>
     <minRetailPrice>0</minRetailPrice>
     <isprivate>N</isprivate>
     <isbundle>N</isbundle>
     <currencyid>1000</currencyid>
     <charges>
      <charge>
    <chargetype>
      <chargetypeid>JCB_CHRG_TYP_00001</chargetypeid>
    </chargetype>
    <chargeid>FD30096C19AD4681E0437E0910ACD407</chargeid>
    <chargeperiodid>JCB_CHRG_PER_00002</chargeperiodid>
    <ratingtype>RF</ratingtype>
    <charge_calculation>S</charge_calculation>
    <entity_type>OFFERPRICE</entity_type>
    <prorate_on_cancellation>Y</prorate_on_cancellation>
    <balanceimpacts>
      <balanceimpact>
        <scaledPrice>1</scaledPrice>
        <fixedPrice>0</fixedPrice>
        <unitqty>1</unitqty>
        <prorate>Y</prorate>
        <resourceid>1000</resourceid>
        <resourcetype>CURRENCY</resourcetype>
        <pricetype>A</pricetype>
      </balanceimpact>
    </balanceimpacts>
      </charge>
      <charge>
    <chargetype>
      <chargetypeid>JCB_CHRG_TYP_00002</chargetypeid>
    </chargetype>
    <chargeid>FD30096C19B14681E0437E0910ACD407</chargeid>
    <chargeperiodid>JCB_CHRG_PER_00005</chargeperiodid>
    <ratingtype>O</ratingtype>
    <charge_calculation>S</charge_calculation>
    <entity_type>OFFERPRICE</entity_type>
    <prorate_on_cancellation>Y</prorate_on_cancellation>
    <balanceimpacts>
      <balanceimpact>
        <scaledPrice>0</scaledPrice>
        <fixedPrice>0</fixedPrice>
        <unitqty>1</unitqty>
        <prorate>Y</prorate>
        <resourceid>1000</resourceid>
        <resourcetype>CURRENCY</resourcetype>
        <pricetype>A</pricetype>
      </balanceimpact>
    </balanceimpacts>
      </charge>
     </charges>
   </offerprice>
   <offerprice type="MP">
     <priceid>FD30096C19CC4681E0437E0910ACD407</priceid>
     <parentpriceid>FD31086465874D5BE0437E0910AC671A</parentpriceid>
     <minQty>10</minQty>
     <staticQuantity>N</staticQuantity>
     <minRetailPrice>1</minRetailPrice>
     <isprivate>N</isprivate>
     <isbundle>N</isbundle>
     <currencyid>1001</currencyid>
     <charges>
      <charge>
    <chargetype>
      <chargetypeid>JCB_CHRG_TYP_00009</chargetypeid>
    </chargetype>
    <chargeid>FD30096C19CE4681E0437E0910ACD407</chargeid>
    <chargeperiodid>JCB_CHRG_PER_00002</chargeperiodid>
    <ratingtype>RF</ratingtype>
    <charge_calculation>S</charge_calculation>
    <entity_type>OFFERPRICE</entity_type>
    <prorate_on_cancellation>Y</prorate_on_cancellation>
    <balanceimpacts>
      <balanceimpact>
        <scaledPrice>1</scaledPrice>
        <fixedPrice>0</fixedPrice>
        <unitqty>1</unitqty>
        <prorate>Y</prorate>
        <resourceid>1001</resourceid>
        <resourcetype>CURRENCY</resourcetype>
        <pricetype>A</pricetype>
      </balanceimpact>
    </balanceimpacts>
      </charge>
      <charge>
    <chargetype>
      <chargetypeid>JCB_CHRG_TYP_00010</chargetypeid>
    </chargetype>
    <chargeid>FD30096C19D24681E0437E0910ACD407</chargeid>
    <chargeperiodid>JCB_CHRG_PER_00005</chargeperiodid>
    <ratingtype>O</ratingtype>
    <charge_calculation>S</charge_calculation>
    <entity_type>OFFERPRICE</entity_type>
    <prorate_on_cancellation>Y</prorate_on_cancellation>
    <balanceimpacts>
      <balanceimpact>
        <scaledPrice>0</scaledPrice>
        <fixedPrice>0</fixedPrice>
        <unitqty>1</unitqty>
        <prorate>Y</prorate>
        <resourceid>1001</resourceid>
        <resourcetype>CURRENCY</resourcetype>
        <pricetype>A</pricetype>
      </balanceimpact>
    </balanceimpacts>
      </charge>
     </charges>
   </offerprice>
   <offerprice type="MP">
     <priceid>FD310864657D4D5BE0437E0910AC671A</priceid>
     <parentpriceid>FD30096C19AB4681E0437E0910ACD407</parentpriceid>
     <minQty>10</minQty>
     <staticQuantity>N</staticQuantity>
     <minRetailPrice>1</minRetailPrice>
     <isprivate>N</isprivate>
     <isbundle>N</isbundle>
     <currencyid>1000</currencyid>
     <charges>
      <charge>
    <chargetype>
      <chargetypeid>JCB_CHRG_TYP_00009</chargetypeid>
    </chargetype>
    <chargeid>FD310864657F4D5BE0437E0910AC671A</chargeid>
    <chargeperiodid>JCB_CHRG_PER_00002</chargeperiodid>
    <ratingtype>RF</ratingtype>
    <charge_calculation>S</charge_calculation>
    <entity_type>OFFERPRICE</entity_type>
    <prorate_on_cancellation>Y</prorate_on_cancellation>
    <balanceimpacts>
      <balanceimpact>
        <scaledPrice>1</scaledPrice>
        <fixedPrice>0</fixedPrice>
        <unitqty>1</unitqty>
        <prorate>Y</prorate>
        <resourceid>1000</resourceid>
        <resourcetype>CURRENCY</resourcetype>
        <pricetype>A</pricetype>
      </balanceimpact>
    </balanceimpacts>
      </charge>
      <charge>
    <chargetype>
      <chargetypeid>JCB_CHRG_TYP_00010</chargetypeid>
    </chargetype>
    <chargeid>FD31086465834D5BE0437E0910AC671A</chargeid>
    <chargeperiodid>JCB_CHRG_PER_00005</chargeperiodid>
    <ratingtype>O</ratingtype>
    <charge_calculation>S</charge_calculation>
    <entity_type>OFFERPRICE</entity_type>
    <prorate_on_cancellation>Y</prorate_on_cancellation>
    <balanceimpacts>
      <balanceimpact>
        <scaledPrice>0</scaledPrice>
        <fixedPrice>0</fixedPrice>
        <unitqty>1</unitqty>
        <prorate>Y</prorate>
        <resourceid>1000</resourceid>
        <resourcetype>CURRENCY</resourcetype>
        <pricetype>A</pricetype>
      </balanceimpact>
    </balanceimpacts>
      </charge>
     </charges>
   </offerprice>
  </offerprices>
 </offerDetails>

        <paramEntity>   
           <paramName>serviceID</paramName>
            <paramValue>1010065</paramValue>
        </paramEntity>
        <paramEntity>   
           <paramName>serviceName</paramName>
            <paramValue>Alertsec Total Endpoint Security</paramValue>
        </paramEntity>
        <paramEntity>   
           <paramName>serviceType</paramName>
            <paramValue>Anti-Malware</paramValue>
        </paramEntity>
        <paramEntity>   
           <paramName>serviceVendorName</paramName>
            <paramValue>jamcracker</paramValue>
        </paramEntity>
        <paramEntity>   
           <paramName>InternalService</paramName>
            <paramValue></paramValue>
        </paramEntity>
        <paramEntity>   
           <paramName>OrderOfferId</paramName>
            <paramValue></paramValue>
        </paramEntity>
        <paramEntity>   
           <paramName>OrderOption</paramName>
            <paramValue></paramValue>
        </paramEntity>
        <paramEntity>   
           <paramName>OrderServiceId</paramName>
            <paramValue></paramValue>
        </paramEntity>
        <paramEntity>   
           <paramName>Pricing</paramName>
            <paramValue></paramValue>
        </paramEntity>
        <paramEntity>   
           <paramName>Publisher</paramName>
            <paramValue></paramValue>
        </paramEntity>
        <paramEntity>   
           <paramName>Resell</paramName>
            <paramValue></paramValue>
        </paramEntity>
        <paramEntity>   
           <paramName>ResellOfferId</paramName>
            <paramValue></paramValue>
        </paramEntity>
        <paramEntity>   
           <paramName>ResellRestrict</paramName>
            <paramValue></paramValue>
        </paramEntity>
        <paramEntity>   
           <paramName>ResellServiceId</paramName>
            <paramValue></paramValue>
        </paramEntity>
        <paramEntity>   
           <paramName>STP</paramName>
            <paramValue></paramValue>
        </paramEntity>
        <paramEntity>   
           <paramName>TestDrive</paramName>
            <paramValue></paramValue>
        </paramEntity>
        <paramEntity>   
           <paramName>TestDriveOfferId</paramName>
            <paramValue></paramValue>
        </paramEntity>
        <paramEntity>   
           <paramName>TestDriveServiceId</paramName>
            <paramValue></paramValue>
        </paramEntity>
</offer>
```

And below file is my `xslt`(What I did so far):

```
    <offerprices>
        <xsl:for-each select="offerprice">
            <xsl:if test="self::node()[@type = $vOfferPriceTypeMP]">

                <offerprice type="MP">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="priceid" />
                    <parentpriceid></parentpriceid>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="minQty" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="staticQuantity" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="minRetailPrice" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="isprivate" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="isbundle" />
                    <currencyid>1003</currencyid>
                    <inCatalog>Y</inCatalog>
                    <globalPriceOverride>N</globalPriceOverride>
                    <priceChangeIndicator>N</priceChangeIndicator>
                    <offerLevelId>00200D7A6EC69B07E05010AC20090AAE</offerLevelId>

                    <charges>
                        <charge>
                        <xsl:attribute name="typeid">
                            <xsl:value-of select="charges/charge/chargetype/chargetypeid" />
                            </xsl:attribute>

                            <xsl:for-each select="charges/charge">


                                <chargeid>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="chargeid" />
                                </chargeid>
                                <chargeperiodid>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="chargeperiodid" />
                                </chargeperiodid>


                                <ratingtype>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="ratingtype" />
                                </ratingtype>
                                <charge_calculation>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="charge_calculation" />
                                </charge_calculation>
                                <entity_type>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="entity_type" />
                                </entity_type>
                                <setupSKUCode>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="setupSKUCode" />
                                </setupSKUCode>

                                <prorate_on_cancellation>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="prorate_on_cancellation" />
                                </prorate_on_cancellation>


                                <xsl:for-each select="balanceimpacts/balanceimpact">
                                    <balanceimpacts>
                                        <balanceimpact>
                                            <scaledPrice>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="scaledPrice" />
                                            </scaledPrice>
                                            <fixedPrice>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="fixedPrice" />
                                            </fixedPrice>
                                            <unitqty>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="unitqty" />
                                            </unitqty>
                                            <prorate>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="prorate" />
                                            </prorate>
                                            <resourceid>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="resourceid" />
                                            </resourceid>
                                            <resourcetype>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="resourcetype" />
                                            </resourcetype>
                                            <pricetype>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="pricetype" />
                                            </pricetype>
                                        </balanceimpact>
                                    </balanceimpacts>

                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </charge>

                    </charges>

                </offerprice>
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="self::node()[@type = $vOfferPriceTypeISV]">
                <offerprice type="ISV">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="priceid" />
                    <parentpriceid />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="minQty" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="staticQuantity" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="minRetailPrice" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="isprivate" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="isbundle" />
                    <currencyid>1003</currencyid>
                    <inCatalog>Y</inCatalog>
                    <globalPriceOverride>N</globalPriceOverride>
                    <priceChangeIndicator>N</priceChangeIndicator>
                    <offerLevelId>00200D7A6EC69B07E05010AC20090AAE</offerLevelId>
                    <charges>
                        <charge>
                            <xsl:attribute name="typeid">
                            <xsl:value-of select="charges/charge/chargetype/chargetypeid" />
                             </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:for-each select="charges/charge">


                                <chargeid>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="chargeid" />
                                </chargeid>
                                <chargeperiodid>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="chargeperiodid" />
                                </chargeperiodid>


                                <ratingtype>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="ratingtype" />
                                </ratingtype>
                                <charge_calculation>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="charge_calculation" />
                                </charge_calculation>
                                <entity_type>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="entity_type" />
                                </entity_type>
                                <setupSKUCode>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="setupSKUCode" />
                                </setupSKUCode>
                                <prorate_on_cancellation>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="prorate_on_cancellation" />
                                </prorate_on_cancellation>


                                <xsl:for-each select="balanceimpacts/balanceimpact">
                                    <balanceimpacts>
                                        <balanceimpact>
                                            <scaledPrice>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="scaledPrice" />
                                            </scaledPrice>
                                            <fixedPrice>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="fixedPrice" />
                                            </fixedPrice>
                                            <unitqty>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="unitqty" />
                                            </unitqty>
                                            <prorate>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="prorate" />
                                            </prorate>
                                            <resourceid>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="resourceid" />
                                            </resourceid>
                                            <resourcetype>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="resourcetype" />
                                            </resourcetype>
                                            <pricetype>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="pricetype" />
                                            </pricetype>
                                        </balanceimpact>
                                    </balanceimpacts>

                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </charge>

                    </charges>

                </offerprice>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </offerprices>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And I need output file is like this:

```
<offerDetails>
    <offerCode>AlertsecTotalEndpointSecuritydummyy</offerCode>
    <Locale value="en_US">
    <offerName>Alertsec Total Endpoint Security dummyy</offerName>
    <offerDescription>Alertsec Total Endpoint Security</offerDescription>
    <unitPriceDesc>User</unitPriceDesc>
    </Locale>
    <currencies>
            <currency>
                <currencyId>1003</currencyId>
            </currency>
        </currencies>
        <offerLevels>
            <offerLevel>
                <offerLevelId>00200D7A6EC69B07E05010AC20090AAE</offerLevelId>
                <name>Default</name>
                <languageCode>en_US</languageCode>
            </offerLevel>
            </offerLevels>

   <offerprices>
   <offerprice type="ISV">
     <priceid>E75AD77694DE439BE043DA0A10AC1840</priceid>
     <parentpriceid></parentpriceid>
     <minQty>1</minQty>
     <staticQuantity>N</staticQuantity>
     <minRetailPrice>0</minRetailPrice>
     <isprivate>N</isprivate>
     <isbundle>N</isbundle>
     <currencyid>1003</currencyid>
     <inCatalog>Y</inCatalog>
    <globalPriceOverride>N</globalPriceOverride>
    <priceChangeIndicator>N</priceChangeIndicator>
    <offerLevelId>00200D7A6EC69B07E05010AC20090AAE</offerLevelId>
     <charges>

 <!-- <charge>
    <chargetype> -->
      <charge typeid="JCB_CHRG_TYP_00001">
     <!--</chargetype> -->
    <chargeid>E75AD77694E0439BE043DA0A10AC1840</chargeid>
    <chargeperiodid>JCB_CHRG_PER_00002</chargeperiodid>
    <ratingtype>RF</ratingtype>
    <charge_calculation>S</charge_calculation>
    <entity_type>OFFERPRICE</entity_type>
    <setupSKUCode></setupSKUCode>
    <prorate_on_cancellation>Y</prorate_on_cancellation>
    <balanceimpacts>
      <balanceimpact>
        <scaledPrice>1</scaledPrice>
        <fixedPrice>0</fixedPrice>
        <unitqty>1</unitqty>
        <prorate>Y</prorate>
        <resourceid>1003</resourceid>
        <resourcetype>CURRENCY</resourcetype>
        <pricetype>A</pricetype>
      </balanceimpact>
    </balanceimpacts>
      </charge>
     <!-- <charge>
    <chargetype> -->
      <charge typeid="JCB_CHRG_TYP_00002">
     <!--</chargetype> -->
    <chargeid>E75AD77694E4439BE043DA0A10AC1840</chargeid>
    <chargeperiodid>JCB_CHRG_PER_00005</chargeperiodid>
    <ratingtype>O</ratingtype>
    <charge_calculation>S</charge_calculation>
    <entity_type>OFFERPRICE</entity_type>
    <setupSKUCode>AlertsecTotalEndpointSecuritydummyy</setupSKUCode>
    <prorate_on_cancellation>Y</prorate_on_cancellation>
    <balanceimpacts>
      <balanceimpact>
        <scaledPrice>1</scaledPrice>
        <fixedPrice>0</fixedPrice>
        <unitqty>1</unitqty>
        <prorate>Y</prorate>
        <resourceid>1000</resourceid>
        <resourcetype>CURRENCY</resourcetype>
        <pricetype>A</pricetype>
      </balanceimpact>
    </balanceimpacts>
      </charge>
     </charges>
   </offerprice>
   <offerprice type="MP">
     <priceid>E75AD77694EF439BE043DA0A10AC1840</priceid>
     <parentpriceid>E75AD77694DE439BE043DA0A10AC1840</parentpriceid>
     <minQty>1</minQty>
     <staticQuantity>N</staticQuantity>
     <minRetailPrice>0</minRetailPrice>
     <isprivate>N</isprivate>
     <isbundle>N</isbundle>
     <currencyid>1003</currencyid>
     <inCatalog>Y</inCatalog>
    <globalPriceOverride>N</globalPriceOverride>
    <priceChangeIndicator>N</priceChangeIndicator>
    <offerLevelId>00200D7A6EC69B07E05010AC20090AAE</offerLevelId>
     <charges>
      <!-- <charge>
    <chargetype> -->
      <charge typeid="JCB_CHRG_TYP_00009">
     <!--</chargetype> -->
    <chargeid>E75AD77694F1439BE043DA0A10AC1840</chargeid>
    <chargeperiodid>JCB_CHRG_PER_00002</chargeperiodid>
    <ratingtype>RF</ratingtype>
    <charge_calculation>S</charge_calculation>
    <entity_type>OFFERPRICE</entity_type>
    <setupSKUCode></setupSKUCode>
    <prorate_on_cancellation>Y</prorate_on_cancellation>
    <balanceimpacts>
      <balanceimpact>
        <scaledPrice>1</scaledPrice>
        <fixedPrice>0</fixedPrice>
        <unitqty>1</unitqty>
        <prorate>Y</prorate>
        <resourceid>1003</resourceid>
        <resourcetype>CURRENCY</resourcetype>
        <pricetype>A</pricetype>
      </balanceimpact>
    </balanceimpacts>
      </charge>
 <!-- <charge>
    <chargetype> -->
      <charge typeid="JCB_CHRG_TYP_00010">
     <!--</chargetype> -->
    <chargeid>E75AD77694F5439BE043DA0A10AC1840</chargeid>
    <chargeperiodid>JCB_CHRG_PER_00005</chargeperiodid>
    <ratingtype>O</ratingtype>
    <charge_calculation>S</charge_calculation>
    <entity_type>OFFERPRICE</entity_type>
    <setupSKUCode>AlertsecTotalEndpointSecuritydummyy</setupSKUCode>
    <prorate_on_cancellation>Y</prorate_on_cancellation>
    <balanceimpacts>
      <balanceimpact>
        <scaledPrice>1</scaledPrice>
        <fixedPrice>0</fixedPrice>
        <unitqty>1</unitqty>
        <prorate>Y</prorate>
        <resourceid>1003</resourceid>
        <resourcetype>CURRENCY</resourcetype>
        <pricetype>A</pricetype>
      </balanceimpact>
    </balanceimpacts>
      </charge>
     </charges>
   </offerprice>
  </offerprices>
 </offerDetails>
```

Here I'm posting my input xml file, xslt file and my output xml file, could anybody guide me how to change input xml to output xml using xslt.

I need a conversion xslt from input xml to output xml.

Comment: You've posted XML with an incomplete XSLT stylesheet that _appears_ to be part of a complete stylesheet that already produces the output given (but we can't tell for sure since the XSLT is incomplete).  You already seem to have all the pieces... what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer would be that you don't get XSLT from any input XML. But as you write the XSLT, you probably need more information about the documents. For example:

1. What exactly do you want to change in the input documents? The input and output look very similar.
2. What other kind of input documents do you want to process? A DTD or an XML Schema would help.
3. What does your Java code have to do with this?

After you've analysed what changes you want to make (1) and what kind of input you want to accept (2), it's quite straightforward to develop the XSLT.

By the way, they shouldn't be called "files" as an XML file is not a well-defined concept. Let's call them XML documents (which can be stored in 0-n files).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this may be of help for you, but as I guess you only want to know how to get the chargetypeid as attribute to each charge instead of just copying it from the input xml.
Don't want to write the full xslt here as you maybe can integrate part form this in your current XSLT and adjust it further to get the output.xml, therefore only the relevant part for your adjustment:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><xsl:stylesheet 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/*">
 <xsl:apply-templates select=".//offerprices"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="offerprices">
 <offerprices>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </offerprices>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="offerprice">
 <offerprice>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::charge"/>
 </offerprice>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="charge">
 <xsl:variable name="chargetypeid" 
  select="normalize-space(descendant::chargetypeid/text())"/>
 <charge>
  <xsl:attribute name="chargetypeid" select="$chargetypeid"/>
    <!-- here your adjusted current code -->
 </charge>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output XML:

```
 <offerprices>
    <offerprice>
      <charge chargetypeid="JCB_CHRG_TYP_00001"/>
      <charge chargetypeid="JCB_CHRG_TYP_00002"/>
    </offerprice>
    <offerprice>
     <charge chargetypeid="JCB_CHRG_TYP_00009"/>
     <charge chargetypeid="JCB_CHRG_TYP_00010"/>
    </offerprice>
  </offerprices>
```

In the template matching "charge" you can handle the rest to adjust your output.
In case you're not so much into XSLT following explanation for getting the chargetypeid: in the template matching "charge" each charge will be processed as the current node. Using the axe "`descendant::`" only descendants of this node will be addressed, matching the node "chargetypeid" - `descendant::chargetypeid`. As you want the value from chargetypeid as attribute for each charge, you're getting the value using `text()`, and in order to remove whitespace the function `normalize-space()` takes care of that.

And as you also don't want to have the chargetype as node in your output but only as attribute of charge, just apply an empy template matching this node and it'll be excluded:

```
<xsl:template match="chargetype"/>
```